# How do I solve for $x$ in this polynomial function?

Tags: functions, polynomials

The marketing manager of a new soap has figured that her monthly profit
$P$ (in thousands of pesos) is determined by the monthly expense $x$ (in terms of thousands of pesos) according to the function:
$$
(x) = x^3 − 15x^2 + 90x \qquad\text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq 5
$$
For what value of $x$ does the manager get Php 184,000.00 in profits?

Comment: You need to solve $x^3-15x^2+90x=184$.  There is a factor and so an integer solution which makes this possible.

Comment: What is the meaning of Php ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Php = philippine peso

Answer (score 0):

With minimal effort of will,

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}0&1&2&3&4&5\\\hline0&
76&
128&
162&
184&
200
\end{array}$$